# Exact working of Keyboard and native APIs at boot time?

Tags: c, keyboard, driver, native, bios

I am testing my code for defragmenation application.I am using two machines one is base machine(win-7/64-bit) and another is virtual machine(winXP/32-bit).In my code I have used native APIs like `NtCreateFile`, `NtReadFile` etc. to get the keyboard key press events. I have written some logs for N`tCreateFile` API. My observation is that while testing on base machine `NtCreateFile` creates one instance of `KeyBoardClass0` while onto virtual machine it creates two instances of `KeyBoardClass` i,e, `KeyboardClass0` and `KeyboardClass1`. As I have no knowledge of drivers, I am bit confused about why this is happening.Thank you in advance.

Comment: **Don't** use *arbitrary* **formatting** - it's *obnoxious*.

Comment: You certainly seem to be interested in the keyboard from boot time. Could you elaborate on this "defragmentation application" you're making?